# Graph Abstract Data Type: Search method.

Tags: search, graph

I am implementing a Graph for a school assignment with an adjacency list. I am having troubles with the search method. I would like to ask you the following question:

If you're searching a vertex that is not in the Graph, should it be an error? 
Which is the best criteria to determine if a possible result is an error or not?

Thanks, 
Gonzalo from Argentina (Hope you understand my english.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the element is not there.

An alternative solution could be to use something similar to Scala's `Option` or Haskell's `Maybe`.

Another possible solution is to introduce a pair of methods `boolean contains(VertexID id)` and `Vertex get(VertexID id)`.
The class should use the query method `contains` to search for the presence for the element and the getter only if he knows that the element is there.
Of course `get` should throw a `NoSuchElementException` if it is invoked for a missing element.

Comment: Is it right to throw an exception? When you're searching something you wont always find it.

Comment: I added another possible solution addressing this concern